# How do I convert a Date to Firebase Timestamp

Tags: android, firebase, date, google-cloud-firestore

How can i convert below date to firebase timestamp format ??

Date

> 22-May-2005

Comment: Did the answer help you achieve what you want in Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the following line:

```
var myTimestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date());
```

.fromDate is a static method from the static Timestamp class from Firebase.

Ref: [Firebase Timestamp Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp)